# Firebase In-App Messaging with User Property on Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-in-app-messaging

I’m experimenting with Firebase Events, User Properties and Audiences on Android.

I’m trying to set an user property, use it to target users and send an In-App Message.

```
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).setUserProperty("has_credit", "true")
```

But the In-App Message is never fetched when target with the user property.

I have already registered the user property on Firebase Console and wait 24 hours.

Is it or not mandatory implement Firebase Auth to use User Properties of Analytics? or Am I missing something else?

Thanks!!!